# LINQ expression: Specifing maximum groupby size

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a elegant way of doing following in LINQ or should I write an extension for this

i have a list of objects that need to be grouped by startdate

lets say

09.00,
13.00,
13.00,
13.00,
15.00,

```
var groupedStartDates = startdate.groupby(x => x.StartDate);
```

I need to have maximum size of group to be 2.

Expected result is

```
var groupedStartDates = startDate.GroupBy(x => x.StartDate);
List
    list1 {09.00}
    list2 {13.00; 13.00}
    list3 {13.00}
    list4 {15.00}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the initial grouping you can then group by the index (in the groups) divided by 2 to do a further grouping, then use `SelectMany` to flatten that back out.

```
var result = startDate.GroupBy(x => x.StartDate)
                      .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select((x,i) => new{x,i})
                                            .GroupBy(a => a.i / 2)
                                            .Select(sgrp => sgrp.Select(a => a.x)));
```

Here's a break down of what's going on.  Note curly brackets will represent collections and square will represent object with multiple properties.

Initial data

> 09.00, 13.00, 13.00, 13.00, 15.00

After `GroupBy(x => x.StartDate)`

> [Key:09.00, {09.00}], [Key:13.00, {13.00, 13.00, 13.00}], [Key:15.00, {15.00}]

Now it's going to operate on each group, but I'll show the results for all of them at each step.
After the `Select((x,i) => new{x,i})`

> {[x:09.00, i:0]}, {[x:13.00, i:0], [x:13.00, i:1], [x:13.00, i:2]}, {[x:15.00, i:0]}

After the `GroupBy(a => a.i / 2)`

> {[Key:0, {[x:09.00, i:0]}]}, {[Key:0, {[x:13.00, i:0], [x:13.00, i:1]}], [Key:1, {[x:13.00, i:2]}}, {[Key:0, {[x:15.00, i:0]}}

After the `.Select(sgrp => sgrp.Select(a => a.x))`

> {{09.00}}, {{13.00, 13.00}, {13.00}}, {{15.00}}

And finally the `SelectMany` will flatten that to.

> {09.00}, {13.00, 13.00}, {13.00}, {15.00}

Note that each line represents a collection, but I didn't put curly braces around them as I felt it made it even harder to read.

Or with an extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Bin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int binSize)
{
    return items
        .Select((x,i) => new{x,i})
        .GroupBy(a => a.i / binSize)
        .Select(grp => grp.Select(a => a.x));
}
```

You can make it a little nicer.

```
var result = startDate
    .GroupBy(x => x.StartDate)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.Bin(2));
```

Update: As of .Net 6 they have added the new Linq method `Chuck` that does the same thing as my `Bin` method above.  So now you can do

```
var result = startDate
    .GroupBy(x => x.StartDate)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.Chunk(2));
```

Comment: upvoted because it just worked! but this is melting my mind o.o

Comment: thanks for the step by step explanation. you are a genius!

Comment: Thanks alot for detailed explaination and query. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `Take`:

```
var result= startDate.GroupBy(x => x.StartDate)
                     .Select(x => x.Take(2))
                     .ToList();
```

Each group will contains at most 2 members and additional items of groups will not return.

Comment: OP is not looking for this I guess. Check the expected output.

Comment: This is not what op has asked.

Comment: @RahulSingh I answered base on my understanding from question. Let me know what's expected result :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei - I am neither the downvoter nor OP. I just said that OP is expecting something else.

Comment: @RahulSingh Thank you for your comment.